# comparing lines with awk vs while read line

Tags: sed, awk, ksh, cat

I have two  files one with 17k lines and another one with 4k lines. I wanted to compare position 115 to position 125 with each line in the second file and if there is a match, write the entire line from the first file into a new file. I had come up with a solution where i read the file using 'cat $filename | while read LINE'. but it's taking around 8 mins to complete. is there any other way like using 'awk' to reduce this process time.

my code

```
cat $filename | while read LINE
do
  #read 115 to 125 and then remove trailing spaces and leading zeroes
  vid=`echo "$LINE" | cut -c 115-125 | sed 's,^ *,,; s, *$,,' | sed 's/^[0]*//'`
  exist=0
  #match vid with entire line in id.txt
  exist=`grep -x "$vid" $file_dir/id.txt | wc -l`
  if [[ $exist -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "$LINE" >> $dest_dir/id.txt
  fi
done
```

Comment: With awk you can use `NR` as number of line. This way you will probably save time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is this:

```
FNR==NR {                      # FNR == NR is only true in the first file

    s = substr($0,115,10)      # Store the section of the line interested in 
    sub(/^\s*/,"",s)           # Remove any leading whitespace
    sub(/\s*$/,"",s)           # Remove any trailing whitespace

    lines[s]=$0                # Create array of lines
    next                       # Get next line in first file
}
{                              # Now in second file
    for(i in lines)            # For each line in the array
        if (i~$0) {            # If matches the current line in second file 
            print lines[i]     # Print the matching line from file1
            next               # Get next line in second file
        }
}
```

Save it to a script `script.awk` and run like:

```
$ awk -f script.awk "$filename" "${file_dir}/id.txt" > "${dest_dir}/id.txt"
```

This will still be slow because for each line in second file you need to look at ~50% of the unique lines in first *(assuming most line do in fact match)*. This can be significantly improved if you can confirmed that the lines in the second file are full line matches against the substrings.

---

For full line matches this should be faster:

```
FNR==NR {                      # FNR == NR is only true in the first file

    s = substr($0,115,10)      # Store the section of the line interested in 
    sub(/^\s*/,"",s)           # Remove any leading whitespace
    sub(/\s*$/,"",s)           # Remove any trailing whitespace

    lines[s]=$0                # Create array of lines
    next                       # Get next line in first file
}
($0 in lines) {                  # Now in second file
    print lines[$0]     # Print the matching line from file1
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that lines in the second file are full line matches against the substring from first file.

Comment: @user37774 I have added a script that should be faster for full line matches.